# Regex that matches strings that are all lower case and do not contain specific string

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to ensure that entries in a form 1) are all lower case AND 2) do not contain the string ".net"

I can do either of those separately:

`^((?!.net).)*$` gives me strings that do not contain `.net`.
`[a-z]` only matches lower-cased inputs.  But I have not been able to combine these.

I've tried:

`^((?!.net).)(?=[a-z])*$`
`(^((?!.net).)*$)([a-z])`

And a few others.

Can anyone spot my error?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean there can be no uppercase letters, or the strings should only consist of lowercase letters?

Comment: the string should only contain lowercase letters.  No wait.  I mean that there should not be uppercase letters.

Comment: Note that `^((?!.net).)(?=[a-z])*$` always matches an empty string. `(^((?!.net).)*$)([a-z])` is closer, it will work like `^(?:(?!\.net)[a-z])*$` - only if you want your string to only consist of lowercase letters.

Comment: You could use `^(?!.*\.net)[^\nA-Z]+$` or

Comment: `^(?!.*\.net)[^\nA-Z]+$` was the answer!

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew!!

Comment: A string that contains `".net"` is not all lowercase - there's a dot in that, so `^[a-z]+$` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using a dot in your pattern that would match any char except a newline, you can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to exclude matching uppercase chars or a newline.

As suggested by @[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew), to rule out a string that contains `.net` you can use a negative lookahead `(?!.*\.net)` where the `.net` *(note to escape the dot)* is preceded by `.*` to match 0+ times any character.

```
^(?!.*\.net)[^\nA-Z]+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*\.net)` negative lookahead to make sure the string does not contain `.net`
- `[^\nA-Z]+` Match 1+ times any character except a newline or a char A-Z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pFpwHj/1)